# SQL -Merge two Tables into one

Tags: mysql

I have two tables bike and car.

Bike table

```
bikeID | name |desc
```

Car table

```
carID | name | desc.
```

I need to merge both tables into one like this

```
bikeID | carID | name | desc
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the tables? Are the same named fields foreign key?

Comment: Whay do you mean merge, like forever or for a select statement?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to have: `VehicleID` | `VehicleType` | `Name` | `Desc`

Comment: It is imperative in order to receive an answer to this, to provide some information regarding the relations between tables.

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right try to use `UNION`

```
SELECT * INTO NEW_TABLEN_NAME FROM
(
SELECT BikeId, NULL as CarID, name,desc FROM Bike
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as BikeId, CarID, name,desc FROM Car
) T
```

Comment: Now I got carID and bikeID fields.but the bikeID is null and carID shows both values(carID and bikeID)

Comment: @nithin I guess you should check the first part of union if it selects `BikeId, NULL as CarID` from `Bike` table